# How can I integrate this with a change of variables?

Tags: calculus, integration, inequality

Consider the region $\mathcal{R}$ defined by

$$
\mathcal{R} = \begin{cases}
0\leq x \leq 60\\
0 \leq y \leq 60 \\
y \leq x+15\\
y \geq x-15
\end{cases}
$$

I'd like to find the area of $\mathcal{R}$ using double integration but am having trouble setting up the bounds for the integrals.  I highly suspect I can use a change of coordinates to accomplish this.

Any help is appreciated, but a hint would be better than a full solution.

Comment: As always, drawing a picture makes short work of multiple integration. I suspect you will need two integrals here.

Comment: You want to kill a fly with a sledgehammer. It took me 30 seconds to draw a little sketch and realize that the area to be computed is a square $60 \times 60$ minus two triangles which can be grouped into a square $45 \times 45$. The area is thus $60^2-45^2=1575$...

Comment: @JeanMarie, yea drawing a picture is def the easy way to go.  This was just to see if I could do it with a change of variables.